# This question with my favorite tag is hidden

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

So I have both JavaScript and jQuery in my favorite tags, so why is this question hidden? In my preferences I have checked "gray out questions in your ignored list", but I don't have either of the tags in my ignored list.

[image: Hidden question with favorite tags]

**Update - Example 2:**

3 out of 4 tags are in my favorite list, and the last one is not in my ignored list. Question's tags hasn't been edited.

[image]

**Another Update**

I was expecting someone from SO team to reply with "We'll look into this, will update shortly" or something. How long does it take for them to reply to a "bug" tag? At least something like "This is low priority for us, we'll look into it when we can.". Anything I can do to get a reply?

Comment: Caching, it's always caching. Check the revision history for that question and you'll see it used to have a tag you have ignored.

Comment: @CodeCaster That doesn't seem to be the case http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35520914/revisions

Comment: Ok, and which list are you browsing?

Comment: @CodeCaster This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

Comment: This could conceivably be the only way to legitimately report the front page not having enough jQuery as a bug. You win the Internet today.

Comment: I can see that you're trying to have a particular question not be grayed-out. You should drop that and try jquery.

Comment: They have yellow background because some tags are in your favourites. They should be grayed out if some of the tags is in ignored list.

Comment: @Qwertiy Please see the 2nd example, 3 out of 4 tags are in my favourites list, the 4th tag is not in my ignored list. That question shouldn't be hidden.

Comment: The SO team is too busy with Teams, CVs & Documentation to be fixing non-breaking bugs with the core of the site _smh_